# How to animate show / hide slide effect with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a simple steps page and would like to add a slide effect.
My problem is the strange behavior of the effect slide. 
The div should enter is shown for a moment under the div that has to come out.
I tried to work with the delay and with the execution time but have not been able to solve.

HTML

```
<fieldset>
   <div id="one"></div>
   <br />
   <a class="next">next</a>    
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <div id="two"></div>
   <br />
   <a class="prev">prev</a>
   <a class="next">next</a>    
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <div id="three"></div>
   <br />
   <a class="prev">prev</a>
</fieldset>
```

JS

```
$(".next").click(function(){
  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 0);
  current_fs.hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 0);
});

$(".prev").click(function(){
  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 0);
  current_fs.hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 0);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/03L50dkm/)

How could I do? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of the async nature of animations. You have to chain animations to prevent them starting all at once.

The behavior comes because you are just executing two animations at once.

You have to

1. Start hiding
2. Wait for hiding to end
3. Start showing

> [See my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03L50dkm/5/)
>
> [Refer to: jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

#### Solution

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    next_fs.hide(); // this fixes your css
    current_fs.hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, function() {
        next_fs.show("slide", { direction: "left" });
    });
});

$(".prev").click(function(){
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    current_fs.hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, function() {
        previous_fs.show("slide", { direction: "right" });
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't see anything different happening.

Comment: now it works. i corrected the directions of the animations too.

Comment: So it seems to work, but I do not understand why you had to fix the css only in next function.

Comment: Remove this line and you will see. Your CSS Selector makes the first item visible. Somehow when the first item starts hiding this selector applies and shows the second item before hiding ends. so i forced it to keep hiding until hiding of the first finished.

Comment: How can I change my css for remove the fix? Thanks.

Comment: I think it is best to leave it out and initialize the first component programmatically like $("#one"),show() or $("fieldset:first").show()